# openRTMFP cumulus how to compile and install

Tags: compilation, openssl, poco, luajit, cumulus

i've just downloaded cumulus, POCO, OpenSSL and LuaJIT and visual studio. now i'm trying to compile it as it said in instruction [here](https://github.com/OpenRTMFP/Cumulus/wiki/Installation#windows-build)

however i've never used visual studio and i've never programed on visual c. so i'm stuck at the very begining.

in instruction i've put link above said "**Visual Studio 2008/2010 solution and project files are included. It searchs external librairies in External/lib folder and external includes in External/include folder in the root Cumulus folder. So you must put POCO, OpenSSL and LuaJIT headers and libraries in these folders.**". i tryed everything but compiler can't find 'Poco/foundation.h'.

and it seems to me if i deal with this error there will more over.

so if someone has expirience in compiling cumulus-server please help me to deal with it.

thanks a lot for you help!

Answer (score 0):

**step 1** - create 2 files
cumulus_root_folder/external/lib
cumulus_root_folder/external/include
**step 2** - put the headers into the include folder from the other 3 dependent projects
dependent projects are: openssl, poco, luajit.
put openssl file into the external/include from openssl-version/include
put Poco file into the external/include from poco-version/Foundation/include
put SAX, DOM, XML files into the external/include/Poco from poco-version/XML/include/Poco
put Net file into the external/include/Poco from poco-version/Net/include/Poco
put Util file into the external/include/Poco from poco-version/Util/include/Poco
put LuaJIT's headers with the same way.
now you can build cumuluslib.
**step 3** - Open your cumuluslib project with specific visual studio version then build it.
When it's done you can see the lib file at cumulus_root_folder/cumuluslib/lib
**step 4** - now you have to build the 3 dependent projects and put their lib files to cumulus_root_folder/external/lib its tough mission, maybe you will need 32-bit windows. Do not forget: when you building poco, do it with debug if not, some of your files will be missing.
When you done with building and gathering lib files you can build cumulusserver. Same way as cumuluslib. Then your cumulus.exe will be in cumulus_root_folder/cumulusserver/debug